# Does intel core i5 belong to the family i686 or x86_64

Tags: x86, x86-64, 64-bit, intel, 32-bit

To which family does intel core i5 processors belong to? x86_64 or i686.

I was installing MinGW. I know it auto selects i686. But i686's are all 32 bit right? and intel i5 is actually a 64bit processor. This sprung up the doubt as to which family does it belong to?

Comment: @Jonas: Thanks for your edits to fix tags, but please add appropriate tags when they apply, like in this case [x86] and [x86-64].  In other cases, there is a [cpu-core] tag which covers that mis-usage of [core].  Also, questions about CPU internals should usually be tagged [cpu-architecture].  (I think you've been adding some tags sometimes, and I don't mind editing questions that got bumped already, but hopefully that'll help.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both. When running in 64-bit mode, it is x86_64. In 32-bit mode, it is i686.

Answer (score 0):

As 64-bit processors, Core i3, i5 and i7 are all part of the x86_64 family.